# Difference between "set" and "interval"

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

*(i)* The Nested Interval Property remains true if the term "closed interval"   is replaced by "closed set".

I think this is false because nested intervals of a set can be constructed such that $\bigcap I_n = \emptyset$ Especially if we are dealing with a set of rational numbers.

*(ii)* Every nonempty open set contains a rational number.

I think this is false. What if the open set consists of multiples or fractions of $\sqrt{2}$ ?

*(iii)* Every bounded infinite closed set contains a rational number.

I think it's false for the same reason. Unless I am missing something here. For some reason I'm having trouble applying these concepts to sets as opposed to intervals. As always, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

(i) Let $I_n=[n,\infty)$.

(ii) Let $U$ be open and nonempty, say $a\in U$. Then for some $r>0$, $(a-r,a+r)\subseteq U$. There is a rational already in $(a-r,a+r)$, for example look for denominators $> \frac 1{2r}$.

(iii) Consider $\{\sqrt 2\}\cup\{\,\sqrt 2+\frac1n\mid n\in\Bbb N\,\}$

Answer (score 1):

(ii) is true because there exists a rational number inbetween every two real numbers, and every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of open intervals.

(ii) For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists a sequence of rational numbers converging to $x$, and that sequence is bounded. Now add $\pi$ to each term of the sequence...

Comment: I guess I'm confused because, what if the set is like $A=\left\{ a: a= \sqrt{2} + n, n \in \mathbb{N}, a\in \mathbb{R} \right\} $? It seems to me that a set can consist of discrete elements, and we can't just put a rational number between the elements. Right?

Comment: @Jabernet that isn't an open set.

Comment: @QthePlatypus True. If I make it an open set, then it can contain rational numbers? I am missing something here. An open set won't contain the endpoints, I know that. So we can assume there is some $V_\epsilon$ around the endpoint that does contain a rational number?